Price Elasticity of Demand over time in Spotfire
I use the following formula to get the 'Period-to-Period' revenue delta:
Sum([Revenue]) THEN ([Value] / First([Value]) OVER (NavigatePeriod([Axis.X],0,-1))) - 1

I would like to do something similar where I calculate the 'Price Elasticity of Demand' to see if the demand elasticity is changing with time (see formula below). I have the following data:

Average Price (I assume it would be: Sum(Avg([Price])))
Quantity (I assume it would be: Sum([Quantity]))


I tried the following, but it seems to break in a few different ways, depending on how I do the parenthesis - How can I fix this?
Sum([Quantity]) THEN (([Value] - First([Value]))/First([Value])) OVER (NavigatePeriod([Axis.X],0,-1)) - 1 / Sum([TotalRevenue]) / Sum([Quantity]) THEN (([Value] - First([Value]))/First([Value])) OVER (NavigatePeriod([Axis.X],0,-1)) - 1 as [Elasticity]

